# Code Sample - ReactJS - Server side rendering - Adobe Test and Target

Tags: adobe, ab-testing

We have a react app and the page is rendered on the server side.

We are Trying to render different react components (A or B or C) based on the Adobe Test and Target AB test. Approach is, Node will communicate with Abode TNT to find the experience and render desired React components accordingly.

Since we have Redux so we will store the experienceId in the store and render the respective react component which team have build already

Please assist with a code sample.

Traffic split

- content: "{"activityId":164422,"experienceId":"A"}" - React Component
  A - 25%
- content: "{"activityId":164422,"experienceId":"B"}" - React 
  Component B - 25%
- content:
  "{"activityId":164422,"experienceId":"C"}" - React Component C - 50%